# drupal facebook friends request

Tags: facebook, drupal

I am using drupal 7 and user relationship module

I had already made a friends search same as that of facebook. Now i want users to send friendship request same as that of facebook request.

plzz help

Answer (score 0):

"User Relationship Elaborations lets users send a message with their relationship request to another user."

I don't know how User Relationship module work. I use [Flag Friend](http://drupal.org/project/flag_friend), which have user friendship request working well.